# SQLite Android Inner join

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I have one strange issue. I am fetching data from server and inserting it into tables. After insertion I query that data using inner join between two tables. 
here is my query :

```
Select 
    F._id, F.id, F.logo, F.total_like, F.distance, F.store_name, F.mob_no_1,
    F.mob_no_2, F.mob_no_3, F.tel_no_1, F.tel_no_2, F.tel_no_3, F.description,
    R.total_record, R.total_page, R.current_page 
from 
    FAVOURITE_STORES as F 
    INNER JOIN FAVOURITE_RECORDS as R on F.area_id = R.area_id 
where 
    F.area_id = 2 and 
    R.area_id = 2
```

I get the cursor count as 1 on some devices and on some devices I get cursor count as zero. Even if the data is there in table.

here is my select query function

```
public Cursor rawQuery(String sQuery,String[] selectionArgs) {
        if(mDatabase == null) {
            mDatabase = getWritableDatabase();
        }
        debug("Query "+sQuery);
        return mDatabase.rawQuery(sQuery,selectionArgs);
    }
```

Cursor class

```
public class ExampleCursorLoader extends CursorLoader {
    private Activity mActivity;
    private String msQuery;
    private DBUtil mDbUtil;
    private String[] mSelectionArgs;

    public ExampleCursorLoader(Activity context, String query,String[] selectionArgs) {
        super(context);
        this.mActivity = context;
        this.msQuery = query;
        this.mSelectionArgs = selectionArgs;
        this.mDbUtil = DBUtil.getInstance(mActivity.getApplicationContext());
    }

    public ExampleCursorLoader(Activity context, String query) {
        this(context,query,null);
        debug(query);
    }
    public Cursor loadInBackground() {  
        debug("Loading in Background");
        Cursor cursor=null;
        cursor = mDbUtil.rawQuery(msQuery,mSelectionArgs);
        return cursor;
    }

    private void debug(String s) {
        Log.v("Adapter " , "Adapter " + s);
    }

    protected void onStartLoading() {
        forceLoad();
        debug("Started Loading");
    }

    protected void onStopLoading() {
        super.onStopLoading();
    }


}
```

and this is how I am calling it.

```
return new ExampleCursorLoader(mActivity,sQuery);
```

Device that gives count as 1 is Samsung s3. And zero is Samsung Grand. 
Have any thought or suggestion on this?

Comment: try to execute your query without a loader to indicate that it is really SQLite issue, not your Loader's

Comment: @Drew query is just running fine. I have checked it.

Comment: is it running fine on both devices, giving the same result? if so, the problem is with your Loader

Comment: @Drew can you tell me what could be possibly going wrong?

Comment: If you show me how you use it in your Activity/Fragment et al

Answer (score 1):

> Device that gives count as 1 is Samsung s3. And zero is Samsung Grand.
>   Have any thought or suggestion on this?

This kind of problem is hard to explain because most likely it doesn't throw any error but only shows different and unwanted result.

All what you are able to do is to *"improve query"*:

At first use placeholders and not raw statements:

```
String query = "... where F.area_id = ? and R.area_id = ?";
String[] whereArgs = {"2", "2"};
```

Also you don't need to use `AS` clause, it's enough to say:

```
... from FAVOURITE_STORES F INNER JOIN FAVOURITE_RECORDS R on ...
```

From code that you provided everythings seems correct (query and an usage of rawQuery()).

Comment: @Ragnar I have updated my question. See if you can make any sense out of it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the last section of your WHERE-clause is unnecessary:

```
 and R.area_id=2
```

You've already specified the rows for the FAVOURITE_STORES table to match area_id=2. As the INNER JOIN is performed on that column, it will only return the rows from FAVOURITE_RECORDS where the area_id column matches FAVOURITE_STORES' area_id column.

I'm not sure how the SQLite engine handles this, but it's worth a try.